User Impersonation not working in .NET Core for Windows Authentication
I have an ASP.NET Core (Blazor Server) app (.NET 8) which calls an API. We are using Windows Authentication on both the website and API. This works in multiple (6) different environments. We have a client in that has a VERY locked down Windows Server environment.
When executing the following code:
return await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync(windowsIdentity.AccessToken, async () =>
{
    var response = await HttpRequst<T, T1>(HttpMethod.Post, url, obj);
    return response;
});

We are getting object reference issues when using the browser developer console. Using Event viewer, we were able to see the floowing error:

I have not been able to find much about this via Google, does anyone have any ideas?
FYI, while this works on multiple other Windows 10/11/Server environments, this is the 2nd server they have given us which is having the same issue; they are unwilling to make any changes to their production server policy so I'm hoping to resolve this through a code solution or off to Okta it is.
Also, there is no proxy, and the same code works when the impersonation piece is commented out.
Thanks!

The error message "System.DllNotFoundException: Dll was not found" suggests that the application is trying to load a native DLL, but it cannot find it. Check Dependencies: Verify that all required dependencies, including any native DLLs, are present on the target machine. Ensure that these dependencies are included in your deployment package.Check Architecture: Ensure that the native DLLs are built for the correct architecture that matches your application (e.g., x86 vs. x64).

Besides, ensure that the application has sufficient permissions to access the native DLLs and any directories containing them. This may involve adjusting file permissions or running the application with elevated privileges.

Thanks @Rena. We tried using an admin account but had the same issue. Confirmed both are 64 as well. As for ensuring the dependency DLL's I'm not even sure how I would know what those are! I can't find anything in the MSFT DOCS linking these two items.
